# Why wont my function return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to get this function to return true even after ticking the two check boxes I have on the page. I've been working on this for hours now and running out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
if(myfunction() == true){
    alert('YAY!');
}

function myfunction(){
    if($("input[type=checkbox]").length > 0){
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).find(".CheckboxCheck").show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: its because you are inside of another function!

Comment: please make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see the issue

Comment: because your first condition is true and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry if I'm retarded, can you please clarify? I've checked and the if checked statement does return true for-each checkbox but doesn't seem to carry as the result of the myfunction() funtion.

Comment: as daniel wrote above, you are returning 'true' inside an anonymous function inside your `each` function. once this function exits, it continues your `myfunction` and skips the `else` clause and returns nothing

Comment: Thanks guys, i appreciate the insight. Helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning true from within the function that you passed to `each`, not from `myfunction`. Except in the case that there are no check boxes on your page, and thus the `else` block executes in `myfunction`, `myfunction` is returning `undefined`.

You can do something like this however:

```
if(myfunction() == true){
    alert('YAY!');
}

function myfunction(){
    var returnValue = true;

    if($("input[type=checkbox]").length > 0) {
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                returnValue = true;
                return false; // Stops the each loop.
            }
            else {
                $(this).find(".CheckboxCheck").show();
                returnValue = false;
                return false; // Stops the each loop.
            }
        });
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Now, I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to do, and you will almost certainly need to tweak the code above. I'm just providing it as a way to illustrate how to get a value out of the function passed to `each`. If you're trying to determine if all of the checkboxes are checked, for example, then you'll want your `each` function to look something like this:

```
var returnValue = true;

...

$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** After looking at the second code snippet again, I realized that the `each` loop is unnecessary. If you want to determine if all check boxes are checked, all you need is this:

```
if ($('.checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
   // All .checkbox elements are checked.
}
```

Now, keep in mind that the `:not()` and `:checked` selectors can't utilize the native JS functions, so they are slower, but probably not enough to matter. I prefer the conciseness.

Comment: Perfect, that explains it. Thanks for explaining it in a way i could wrap my head around!

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm creating a user registration form which they have to scroll through the legal docs in order to check the check boxes and before they can move on to the next page they have to agree to all the docs by ticking the check boxes. I got stuck on this part, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Returning from inside the `each` callback function will not return from the outer function. The function will return `undefined` as you haven't specified any return value for it, and that is not equal to `true`.

You can use a variable for the result, that you set from within the loop:

```
function myfunction(){
  var result = true;
  $('.checkbox').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
      result = false;
      $(this).find(".CheckboxCheck").show();
      return false; // exit the loop
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```